# Java get result from Thread and Runnable

Tags: java, android, android-handler

in this below code i can not get result from `getValue` from `Foo` class and thats return `null` but that must be return value. result is correct and this function could not return that. for example this is my class:

```
public class JsonService {
    private JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    public JsonService(final String username, final String password) throws Exception{
        json.put("username", username);
        json.put("password", password);
    }
    public class Foo implements Runnable {
        private String result;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000);
            HttpResponse response;

            try {
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com/json_android.php");
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity( json.toString());
                se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                post.setEntity(se);
                response = client.execute(post);
                if(response!=null){
                    InputStream stream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                    result = convertToString(stream);

                    /*
                         I can Log result with below line
                    */
                    Log.e("response is: ", result);

                    /*
                         result is {"username = ":"Hello"}
                    */
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Error", String.valueOf(e));
            }
        }

        public String getValue() {
            /*
                 return in this fucntion not working
            */
            return result;
        }
    }
    public String request() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        new Thread(foo).start();
        return foo.getValue();
    }
```

How to get result correctly from `Foo` and return that from `reauest()` ? please help me. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [FutureTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) and implement a [Callable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html).

```
public class Foo implements Callable<String> {

    @Override
    public String call() {
        String result = null;
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000);
        HttpResponse response;

        try {
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com/json_android.php");
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity( json.toString());
            se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
            post.setEntity(se);
            response = client.execute(post);
            if(response!=null){
                InputStream stream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                result = convertToString(stream);

                /*
                     I can Log result with below line
                */
                Log.e("response is: ", result);

                /*
                     result is {"username = ":"Hello"}
                */
            }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Error", String.valueOf(e));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

and than use it with the FutureTask

```
public String request() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
   Foo foo = new Foo();
   FutureTask<String> fooFuture = new FutureTask<String>(foo);
   new Thread(fooFuture).start();
   return fooFuture.get();
}
```

Comment: If the computation takes long time dose not make `ANR`? because `fooFuture.get();` blocks till result gets ready!

Answer (score 0):

the method of `get` from class `FutureTask` (at the above answer `return fooFuture.get();`) is a blocking function that means when you call it from UI thread it blocks the UI thread so cause your app sends you `ANR` error. My suggestion to solve it is using `LocalBroadCastManager` and when the computation finished it sends a local `broadcast` and in your UI you will get the result at the `onReceive` from the `Extra` that is embedded in the intent.
another solution is using `ruOnUiThread` or passing the handler from UI thread. and last one is using `post` method of widgets.